# Flink async io doesn't work with elasticsearch on emr cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink job which has the following operator sequence

Custom Source(Kinesis) -> async wait operator -> Filter -> Map -> Sink(ES)

In the Async wait operator, i'm querying elasticsearch and enriching the event received from kinesis. 
In the AsyncFunction, I'm getting a TransportClient in the open method and using the search API in the asyncInvoke method.

This setup works fine on a local cluster. But when I try to run it on EMR, the job is getting submitted correctly. When an event comes from Kinesis it fails to enrich the event with the below error. What could be the cause of the error. How can I debug it ?

```
Caused by: NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: []]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:290)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:288)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:359)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:56)
    at com.a.p.flink.AsyncESRequest.asyncInvoke(AsyncESRequest.java:54)
    at com.a.p.flink.AsyncESRequest.asyncInvoke(AsyncESRequest.java:23)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.async.AsyncWaitOperator.processElement(AsyncWaitOperator.java:230)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:528)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:503)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:483)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:891)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:869)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collect(StreamSourceContexts.java:103)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.KinesisDataFetcher.emitRecordAndUpdateState(KinesisDataFetcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.ShardConsumer.deserializeRecordForCollectionAndUpdateState(ShardConsumer.java:263)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.ShardConsumer.run(ShardConsumer.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Another question is where can I see the logs of the running job when I'm running it in EMR cluster? They don't seem to be getting logged in the main log. I'm using the per-job cluster.

Comment: I believe EMR locks down the network pretty tight by default. Maybe this is a security/firewall issue?

Comment: Thanks @alpinegizmo. I've verifed that I'm able to telnet to the elasticsearch hosts from that machine. Also in the client that submits to the cluster, I ran a simple search and verified that I'm getting the results. that works so there is no problem with security/firewall.

Comment: It turned out to be a proxy issue. It seems the client program is able to connect to the ES as I had set the proxy manually in the client program.  Since the program runs on a task manager, it didn't have the proxy settings. I added the proxy system variables to the env.java.opts and now the ES client is able to connect.